# MS Access : How to relatively refer to a control in master form from subform control for a formula?

Tags: ms-access

In VBA you can refer to master form with something like me.parent.

But let's say you have a formula in a subform control that needs to refer to another control in parent form (for example in a criteria), how can you refer to that parent control without using parent form name ?

Comment: Why? Don't think you can. Not without VBA. The control could call a custom function that has the Me.Parent referencing.

Comment: It's illogical you can by VBA and not in formula

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try:

```
=[Parent]![SomeControlOnParentForm]
```

You may need to be more brave to survive in coding business.

Comment: Here Parent is absolute name reference to the form isn't it ? That's not what I want: I don't want to refer to the parent by its name since when I change the name, it won't work anymore

Comment: It will. Where do you see an "absolute name reference to the form"? The main form can have any name. Again, why don't you just try?

Comment: Ooops, now that I see it in Gustav's example, I do remember that syntax is available in Access. Don't think I've ever needed it. No, Parent is not absolute reference. Don't substitute 'Parent' with form name, use exactly as shown: [Parent].